# How were the rules for Devalaya Vastu forged?

Tags: rituals, temple, art

There are very few references as to how the rules for Devalaya Vastu (देवालय वस्तु) were written.

Any insights on who the original authors were, how and why they wrote the very specific rules that govern the construction of Hindu temples would be great.

Comment: Vastu for temples or temple architecture is mainly described in maymatyam in chapter of nagar nirman and some info on [vastu for temple](http://www.pandit.com/vaastu-for-temples/) you can also check on vishkarma prakash.

Answer (score 5):

Temple and idol construction and Vastu requirements have been elaborately defined in the Matsya Purana, Brihat Samhita and Vishwakarma Prakasha. In addition it also depends on the chief deity to whom the temple is built.

For temples where the presiding deity is Ganapathi, Shiva, Subrahmanya (Karthikeya), Shakti and Dharma Shaashta, the main reference point is the Shaiva Aagama and for Vishnu, Surya and other forms of Narayana and Lakshmi, Vaishnava Aagama is referred to. Additionally, for certain forms of Devi, Tantra Shastra is also brought in for Yantra sthaapana and uddhaara.

Also, Shilpa shastra deals with the construction and sculpting of statues/idols and Vastu shastra deals with the construction of the temple complex and the inner sanctum.

Vishwakarma (who is attributed as the "Purusha" (or the Brahman itself) in the Rig Veda) is the presiding deity for all construction engineering and related crafts.